# Make LLDB break even if the exit code is 0

Tags: debugging, lldb

How do I make LLDB break when the program exits with 0?

The program exits with code 0 when the checksum doesn't match (I guess)
and I'm trying to find that checksum function.

I tried debugging it on Xcode too but still no luck.

Comment: In lldb try a symbolic breakpoint `b exit`. You may get lucky if your debugged program doesn't use syscalls directly to force exit.

Comment: @Kamil.S It worked! And I was able to look through the call stack and find the function. Thanks!